# How execute a commited sql-statement (as parameter) in a procedure and measure the execute time?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to write a function in PL/SQL, which has a sql-statement as parameter. The statement can be DDL,DML and DCL

I want to print the time from the executed statement in the console.

I have following code:

```sql
 create or replace procedure measureTime (statement  IN varchar2 )AS 
--declarations
neededTime INTEGER;
  BEGIN 
    dbms_output.enable; 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement
 COMMIT; 
SELECT ELAPSED_TIME AS neededTime FROM V_$SQL WHERE SQL_TEXT=statement
    dbms_output.put_line('executeTime '|| neededTime);
 END measureTime;
```

But it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a simpler way to do it; simply take the start time before you start and take that off the current time when you've finished.

```
 create or replace procedure measureTime (statement  IN varchar2 )AS 

   l_start_time timestamp default systimestamp;

  BEGIN

    dbms_output.enable;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement;
    COMMIT; 

    dbms_output.put_line('executeTime '|| systimestamp - l_start_time);

  END measureTime;
```

Alternatively if you want it in seconds say change `systimestamp - l_start_time` to `trunc((systimestamp - l_start_time) * 24 * 60 * 60)`

This does seem like an over-worked way to go about things. `execute immediate` will be slightly slower as Oracle has to validate the query before it can run each time. Why are you not just executing the query?

The `commit` will also commit everything that has happened in that session, which may not be what you want.

You should also ensure that you have escaped your `statement` properly to avoid SQL injection.

#### In answer to your question:

Your procedure wouldn't have compiled as you needed a semi-colon after your `execute immediate`. This should **not** be included in the parameter `statement`.

Your syntax for your select is also incorrect. As this is PL/SQL and not SQL you need to use the [into clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345) and you were missing a semi-colon at the end of this statement as well.

```
select elapsed_time 
  into neededTime 
  from v$sql 
 where sql_text = statement;
```

Even without syntax errors there are several reasons your statement might not work for instance, `sql_text` in [`v$sql`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_3043.htm#REFRN30246) only has the first 1,000 characters, so if `statement` is more than 1k characters long there would be no match. If you have a `group by` clause, according to the documentation, statistics are not stored.

Comment: thank you for this example. I've converted the timestamp with `EXTRACT(SECOND FROM systimestamp - l_start_time)` to seconds. Works finde